# Unable to get Debug logs in Qt console while deploying the application in Android 6.0

Tags: android, qt, qt5

I am developing a Qt application in Qt5.5.0 using Qt Creator 3.4.2.
When I am deploying this application on my Nexus 5 device (Android 6.0), I am unable to see any logs.

I have configured my Qt Creator for cross compiling for android platform. Configured details are mentioned below:
JDK version: 1.7.0_25
NDK version: r10

Apache-ant: 1.9.4

Build SDK: android-23

How to solve this issue?